# A movie where a man dreams he's a woman living an alternate life

Tags: story-identification, movie

I haven't seen this. I only read the description when I was purchasing another and thought, "Hmm I'll remember to buy it later" then completely forgot the title. The summary indicated that in his dream the protagonist lives his life as a woman. It may have also been vice-versa. This is not *Freaky Friday*, *Dr Jekyll and Ms.Hyde* or some obscure sci-fi 80s or older movie. From what I remember of the cover, it was at least from the 90s or 2000s to present.

I read this on the back of a DVD case, so it must be a movie not just a book.  The cover was fairly plain, just an ordinary looking man and woman whom appeared to live ordinary lives (so nothing like [*Freaky*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10919380), 2020). It seemed even boring at first glance until I read the summary. There weren't any spoilers, but what was implied was they switch lives when dreaming. Like one spirit going back and forth I guess with at least the man remembering being the woman if not both. It was a live-action movie. I'm adding also that it looked very serious. Not a comedy at all. Seemed like a drama.

The cover was diagonally divided, with the man above and the woman below.
I'm pouring over movie covers right now to try to find it.

The man sleeps and wakes up as the woman. The woman sleeps and wakes up as the man. Anything else could've happened because that's about all I recall.

Comment: Could it have been an anime rather than a live-action movie? There was one called [Your Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Name) that had a story like this.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - That was my immediate thought. May be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the 2008 Korean movie *Dream*.

From [AsianMovieWeb](http://www.asianmovieweb.com/en/reviews/dream.htm):

> Jin (Jo Odagiri) wakes up one day after having had a dream in which he caused a car accident. Even though it has been just a dream Jin is worried because everything felt unusually real. He goes to the accident site and and finds out that he wasn't just dreaming. However, he hasn't been the one causing the accident, but the woman Ran (Lee Na-yeong), who can't remember a thing, though. **It turns out that Ran is sleepwalking and doing exactly what Jin is dreaming.** That's even the more bad, since Jin can't forget his ex-girlfriend (Zia) and visits her every night in his dreams, but when Jin dreams of her, Ran in reality visits her ex-boyfriend (Kim Tae-hyeon), whom she actually despises. **No one wants to believe the strange bond that is linking Jin and Ran**, except a psychiatrist, who advices them to fall in love in order to solve to problem. But this is not something the two are ready for or want to. Thus, the two decide to look out for each other, so that **only one of them sleeps at the same time and the other one stays awake.** Still, this proves to be not that easy...

The movie still is indeed diagonally separated and quite plain, a man and a woman:

[image: original poster, long black-haired woman and man with a bun]

---

Found with [the whatismymovie.com query `man dreams wakes up as woman`](http://whatismymovie.com/results?text=man%20dreams%20wakes%20up%20as%20woman), then scrolling through the results looking for a match in the covers.